# Apply function to multiple rows in data frame

Tags: r

Trying to apply the following to lots of separate rows in a dataframe, containing each 17 values:

```
rsq <- function (x, y) {cor(x, y) ^ 2}

rsq <- function(x,y){
  result <- matrix(0,ncol=ncol(y),nrow = nrow(y))
  for(i in seq(1:nrow(y))){
    fcs <- cor(x, i) ^ 2
    result[i] <- result[i]+fcs
  }
  rownames(result) <- rownames(x)
  return(result)
}
```

Let's take this an example data.frame where I want to apply rsq to data and each gene:

[data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbHuz.png)

Comment: Please show a small reperoducible example

Comment: yes, sorry I meant to take out rowMeans. I'm just trying to loop the rsq function across multiple columns or rows - doesn't matter as I can shift around the data.frame. Importantly, i here doesn't actually grab the entire content of a row...it's just the length 1 of the first row. So the function fails.